# How to get rid of <null> objects when Parsing JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, web-services

For now, I have a working web service calls that returns the titles of the cheapest objects i searched for. For instance if i searched "book", it would return the cheapest books in my area. However, sometimes, I get  objects, like this:

```
2014-06-26 13:14:12.008 FindTheCheapestOne[2244:60b] The Little Book of Champagne
2014-06-26 13:14:12.009 FindTheCheapestOne[2244:60b] The Holy Bible
2014-06-26 13:14:12.010 FindTheCheapestOne[2244:60b] <null>
2014-06-26 13:14:12.010 FindTheCheapestOne[2244:60b] Books of the Hebrew Bible (Study      Guide): Book of Proverbs, Book of Job, Book of Esther, Book of Jeremiah, Book of Isaiah, Song of Songs
2014-06-26 13:14:12.010 FindTheCheapestOne[2244:60b] Book of Job : A Short Reading
2014-06-26 13:14:12.010 FindTheCheapestOne[2244:60b] Book of Jeremiah
```

When I get these objects, I store them into an array, and pass this array to my TableViewController. However, I can't pass these  objects, and therefore I get SIGABRT as a consequence.

Here is how i attempted to fix it:

```
 for (NSDictionary *theItem in itemCallArray)
    {
        NSString *titleString = theItem[@"title"];

        if (titleString !=NULL)
        {

        [titleArray addObject:titleString];

        NSLog(@"%@", titleString);

        }
    }

    ResultsTableViewController *tableVC = (ResultsTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [tableVC setArray:titleArray];

}
```

I still get SIGABRT, and it doesn't fix the problem.

All help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance :)

Comment: What you're getting is not a `nil` but an NSNull object.

Answer (score 0):

A good test for checking a NULL value can be:

```
if (title == (id)[NSNull null] || title.length == 0 )
```

Hope this will help. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I'm not getting any null objects anymore, but now it's saying Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]:

Comment: Ah nevermind, I edited your answer to this: if (titleString != (id)[NSNull null] && titleString.length != 0 ) and now it's working. I'll accept your answer regardless for pointing me in the right direction :)